# Toolbar does not collapse as it should using TabLayout during scroll

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I have a problem with a Toolbar (with TabLayout) during the scroll, as it also hides the notification bar, making it look the title of the toolbar.

[image: problem on scroll]

Here the layout of the activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.testapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/appbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can i solve this? I've seen apps like Google Play or Phonograph not have this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

**UPDATE**

Here is my style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

And style.xml v21

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

About the response of MML13 to remove fitsSystemWindows, it works, but the notification bar loses color, being white.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your style.xml file here.

Comment: style.xml file Posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this.**

**Change this part.**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**To this.**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: @toledorobia Glad to help you :).

Answer (score 0):

***Change***

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exituntilcollapse"
```

***instead of***

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Using "exituntilcollapse" the toolbar is not hidden during scroll.

Answer (score 0):

remove:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from `CoordinatorLayout`

you must use:

valuse style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>
```

values-v21:

```
<style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It works, but the notification bar loses color, being white. I updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: I think you overkill by using a lot of flags. All you need are those two files.